# How do you do unit testing with SQFLITE?

Tags: flutter

I have a database class that handles all my database operations with functions inside it. How do I make unit tests with this, without it messing up my real database and how do I make it so that it always starts from a clean state?

Comment: I would suggest looking into mockito to mock the your database calls: https://pub.dev/packages/mockito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use sqflite_common_ffi so that you can run unit test on your host (mac, linux, win). You can use an in memory database to always start with an empty database without messing your application database.

More information here:

- https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/testing.md#using-sqflite_common_ffi
- https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite_common_ffi/doc/testing.md